# How to assign variables using JSON data in python

Tags: python, json

I wrote a python code using MySQL data, but then I decided to use JSON as a "database" rather than MySQL.

This is MySQL code :

```
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="nn", passwd="passpass")
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    event_fabricant = input('Inscrivez le nom de la compagnie : ')
    mycursor.execute("""SELECT name_company,inspecteur1, inspecteur2, inspecteur3, ville, email FROM listedatabase.entreprises_inspecteurs WHERE name_company = %s""", (event_fabricant,))
    data = mycursor.fetchall()
    if data:
        row = data[0]
        event_location = row[4]
        event_email = row [5]
```

How do I assign data like I did with MySQL but with JSON?

This is a sample of my JSON data, and below what I did so far.

JSON SAMPLE :

```
[
 {
   "id": 1,
   "name_company": "Acier Michel",
   "inspecteur1": "Hou, L",
   "inspecteur2": "Caana, C",
   "inspecteur3": "Luc, C",
   "type": "Water",
   "location": "Laval"
 },
 {
   "id": 2,
   "name_company": "Aciers ABC Inc.",
   "inspecteur1": "Vali, M",
   "inspecteur2": "Alemane, K",
   "inspecteur3": "laszik, M",
   "type": "NA",
   "location": "St-Joseph de Sorel"
 }
]
```

This is what I did so far but it's not exactly what i want :

```
import json


database = "convertcsv.json"
data = json.loads(open(database).read())

name_company = input("type company name: ")
for item in data:
    if item['nom_entreprise'] == name_company:
        print(item['inspecteur1'])
    else:
        print("Not Found")
```

What I need instead is to be able to assign to `variable1` the `inspecteur1` name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to assign the data just use: `variable1 = item["inspecteur1"]`.

One issue with your JSON code above is that it will print `Not Found` for every record that does NOT match which I don't think it's what you want. Try:

```py
found = False
for item in data:
    if item['nom_entreprise'] == name_company:
        print(item['inspecteur1'])
        found = True
if not found:
    print("Not Found")
```

If you feel like MySQL is too complex for your needs, may I suggest [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html)? It's supported out of the box in Python, there's no server process (just a file) and you get all the database features that JSON does not provide by itself.

Comment: Thank you !! Yes, MySQL is way too complex for what I need, I only have about 150 data stored and i wont be doing queries ever. I will look into SQLite.

Comment: But, now that it printed inspecteur1, how do i add lets say inspecteur2, and inspecteur 3 to variable a, and variable b ?

Comment: I don't see these variables (`variable1`, `variable a`, `variable`) in your code but if you want to access those fields you can access them the same as `inspecteur1`; example `print(item['inspecteur1'], item['inspecteur2'], item['inspecteur3'])`